# Change jquery grid theme (ui.jqgrid.css location) in struts2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, struts2

I have a jquery grid component on my webpage. I want to change css file, that it uses. I set it in jj:head tag:

```
<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="custom-theme" customBasepath="css"/>
```

And I see this html tag on my webpage:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" id="jquery_theme_link">
```

Styles files path for jquery-grid component is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/appname/struts/themes/ui.jqgrid.css">
```

I want this path to be like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom-theme/ui.jqgrid.css">
```

Where can I set struts jquery grid css file location?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble, the solution was to override the css once the grid finish loading.

```
<sjg:grid 
    ...
    onCompleteTopics="loadCustomCss"
    ...
/>
```

Then in your jsp

```
<script>
    $.subscribe('loadCustomCss', function(event,data){
         $('head').append( $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').attr('href', '../css/grid.css') );
    });
</script>
```

Where grid.css is your custom css, you can copy the css provided by the plugin and this is especially useful when you had it loaded as a Maven dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as:

```
<sjg:grid ... onGridCompleteTopics="myCssLoaderTopic" ....>
```

An then in your topics

```
<script>
    $.subscribe('loadCustomCss', function(event,data){            
        $.struts2-jquery.requireCss(cssFile, basePath); 
    });
</script>
```

Please refer to: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/struts2-jquery/Aurqeuwhiuo